# Single newline shows up as space with yaml.load

Tags: python, yaml

When using "\n" as a value in yaml, the value is interpreted as " ". And when using "\n\n" as a value, the value is interpreted as "\n". Why is this?

Code to reproduce:

```
import yaml

# One newline results in space
yaml_txt = """value: "\n"
"""
x = yaml.load(yaml_txt, Loader=yaml.SafeLoader)
print(repr(x["value"]))
# ' '

# Two newlines result in one newline
yaml_txt = """value: "\n\n"
"""
x = yaml.load(yaml_txt, Loader=yaml.SafeLoader)
print(repr(x["value"]))
# '\n'
```

Comment: I hope you realise that PyYAML only supports a subset of the YAML 1.1 specification, and that was superceded in 2009 by YAML 1.2. Are you sure developing new programs based on something so outdated is what you want?

Answer (score -1):

The value for your key `value` in your YAML document is a [double quoted style scalar](https://yaml.org/spec/1.1/#id904245) (I am using the YAML 1.1 spec here, the YAML 1.2 spec from 2009 is similar in this respect, but PyYAML doesn't support that).

The relevant section is:

> In a multi-line double-quoted scalar, line breaks are subject to flow line folding, and any trailing white space is excluded from the content. However, an escaped line break (using a “\”) is excluded from the content, while white space preceding it is preserved. This allows double-quoted content to be broken at arbitrary positions.

Flow line folding:

> Line folding allows long lines to be broken for readability, while retaining the original semantics of a single long line. When folding is done, any line break ending an empty line is preserved.

The practical implementation of this in PyYAML is that the a single newline in a double quoted scalar, is loaded as a space, and if there are N newlines with only empty lines between them in your double quoted scalar, you get N-1 newlines in the resulting str.

So if you load the Python string `"abc\nklm"` as YAML you will get `abc klm`, i.e a long line broken for readability, but if you load `"abc\n\nklm"` the second newline is after an empty line and is preserved resulting in `abc\nklm` (so no space before the newline).

Answer (score -2):

This is because of the way YAML handles escape sequences. In YAML, escape sequences are used to represent special characters such as newlines, tabs, and quotes in a string.

```py
yaml_txt = """value: >
  This is a
  multi-line
  string with
  several newlines
"""
x = yaml.load(yaml_txt, Loader=yaml.SafeLoader)
print(repr(x["value"]))
# 'This is a multi-line string with several newlines'
```

In this example, the > block scalar style is used to define a multi-line string, and the newlines are preserved as expected.

Comment: There is no escape sequence in the YAML document of the OP (There is one in the Python source, but that gets resolved by the Python string parser).